# How to setup authorization in Postman in collaborative environment

Tags: authorization, postman

I upgraded Postman to 6.2.5. It allows Teams for free user. Ok, so I created Team and started new collection within it.

On collection level I specified `Authorization` as `OAuth 2.0`, generated new Access token (using the button `Get New Access Token`) so it is now in `Available Tokens`. I don't know if the tokens are shared with other team members (I haven't invited them yet). But there is a hint

```
Heads up! These parameters hold sensitive data. To keep this data secure while working in a collaborative environment, we recommend using variables.
```

[image: See the picture]

I know the variables but don't know how to employ them in this scenario. What is the correct way to setup OAuth 2.0 Authorization in collaborative environment? (I would like to keep it on Collection level so it could be inherited down the structure of folders and requests.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what they mean by that:

Source: https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/team_library/sharing/#sharing-environments

> 1) In addition to the standard way to share an environment, Postman Pro
>   and Enterprise users can also share an environment with their team.
>
> 2) From the gear icon in the upper right corner of the Postman app,
>   select "Manage Environments", and click the orange Share button next
>   to the environment you want to share. You will have one last
>   opportunity to hide any sensitive values like passwords and access
>   tokens before sharing the environment. When someone else imports the
>   environment, or accesses the shared template, they can input their own
>   personal information within their own version of the template.
>   environment

[image: https://s3.amazonaws.com/postman-static-getpostman-com/postman-docs/58787793.png]

> 3) Click the Share button to complete the process.
>   4) Go to the Team Library to view the full list of shared team environments.

Where you have your long access token like: "*a1dfgz51dgs5dg1s21gdsdg*" you'll write {{accessToken}} as it will become an environment variable.